# Does the Android NDK encrypt compiled c++ files?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I have a C++ file on my Android project (`native-lib.cpp`):

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_keysnative_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string api_key = "0123456789abcdef";
    return env->NewStringUTF(api_key.c_str());
}
```

When I build the project and unpack the apk, this file will be compiled into a binary: `lib/x86/libnative-lib.so`.

If I then try importing and use this file into another project I get an error:

```
public class Main {

    static {
        try {
            System.load("/Users/u/Playground/KeysNative/app-debug/lib/x86/libnative-lib.so");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/u/Playground/KeysNative/app-debug/lib/x86/libnative-lib.so: dlopen(/Users/u/Playground/KeysNative/app-debug/lib/x86/libnative-lib.so, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /Users/u/Playground/KeysNative/app-debug/lib/x86/libnative-lib.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00
>       /Users/u/Playground/KeysNative/app-debug/lib/x86/libnative-lib.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00

**Question:** Do these files use the java keystore in the project to be compiled, or any other kind of signature?

Comment: The file you're trying to load is an ELF shared object, which may also have dependencies to Android's somewhat custom libc implementation. Judging by your logs you are trying to load this library on a MacOS system, which will not work, because MacOS uses a different dynamic library format.

Comment: So should trying to run this shared object file in any other android application work? Will confirm in 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load native assemble from your computers file-system on a mobile device.

This should already suffice to link the assembly:

```
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("libnative-lib");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

However, if you only have `x86` assembly, this will only work on a `x86` Android emulator.

Comment: The attempt to load the binary in Java was ran on my computer, it's also on a different directory hence the full path. Trying `System.load("libnative-lib")` throws "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Expecting an absolute path of the library: libnative-lib.so"

Comment: Actually it's `System.loadLibrary("libnative-lib")`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Michael said, because the .so was generated from the Android NDK, it contains Android dependencies, and so can only be ran on an Android system.